# Is it possible to create a multiple labels node with Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I wish create a node like this:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfF9i.png)

I try to use Cytoscape.js with a compound node and 2 child node,
But I got :
[actually result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aoRi.png)

Here is my code:

```
    { data: { id: 'a', parent: 'c', label: 'in:{$in}' }, classes: 'top-left' },
    { data: { id: 'b', parent: 'c', label: 'out:{$out}' }, classes: 'top-right' },
    { data: { id: 'c', label: 'ip: {$ip}' }, classes: 'bottom-center' },
```

Is it possible to got the result with Cytoscape.js?

Thanks in advance.

Norman

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a layout problem, just use this configuration (see [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/documentation/demos/compound-nodes)) for compound nodes:

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,

  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ':parent',
      css: {
        'text-valign': 'top',
        'text-halign': 'center',
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'a',
          parent: 'b'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'b'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'c',
          parent: 'b'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'd'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'e'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'f',
          parent: 'e'
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          id: 'ad',
          source: 'a',
          target: 'd'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'eb',
          source: 'e',
          target: 'b'
        }
      }

    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'grid',
    columns: 2
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <title>Compound nodes</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```